# Need to enable http in OpenSUSE Linux

Tags: linux, http, opensuse

I have newly installed in my machine Linux OpenSUSE. Also i have installed Xampp in that service. After staring the apache i am able to see the PHP apache using localhost url. But when i trying using IP address. Nothing is showing in the page.

That is localhost/xampp.php is working.
But http://10.21.30.220/xampp.php is not working.

I have checked both http port and apache and both ar running.

```
  linux-pott:~ # /opt/lampp/lampp status
  Version: XAMPP for Linux 5.5.19-0
  Apache is running.
  MySQL is running.
  ProFTPD is running.

linux-pott:~ # netstat -tulppn | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      24782/httpd
```

How can i fix my problem. Again i am telling my OS is Linux OpenSUSE.

Comment: are you accessing from another box? BTW, you should try not to give the actual IP address for security reasons.

Comment: i have tried from both same box and other box. Can you please tell me how can i access that URL from other box.

Comment: that is strange (even from the same box). Do you have iptables or any firewall running? Try disabling it and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your xampppath\apache\conf\extra open file httpd-xampp.conf and find the below tag:

```
 # Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

and add

```
"Allow from all"
```

after Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 {line}

Restart xampp, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable firewall using following command

```
 /sbin/SuSEfirewall2 off
```

Comment: i have done both casee Off and on. But still no result. Getting below error
Access forbidden!

New XAMPP security concept:

Access to the requested object is only available from the local network.

This setting can be configured in the file "httpd-xampp.conf".

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

10.21.30.220
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.5.19 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

Comment: In your xampppath\apache\conf\extra open file httpd-xampp.conf and find the below tag:

# Close XAMPP sites here
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

and add

"Allow from all"

after Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8 {line}

Restart xampp, and you are done.